# how to deploy Jsp Project In tomcat server

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I have Successfuly Deploy my Jsp Project On Tomcat Server in Windows . But when i send my  Project to main server (we don't have Full access of Client  Tomcat server  They Gave me FTP for send ) so Using File Zila i am sending My Project to client server then file deployed But only client side code run please check this [http://www.incometaxindiapr.gov.in/incometaxindiacr/cbdt-cir-not/Home.jsp ] when i try to serch any thing from serch Box then  Project gives org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:  Exception . please help me.

NOTE: CLIENT have Linux server in that install Tomcat Server .

Comment: "org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP" You need to get hold of the full error message. It should tell you what the problem is.

Comment: I cant Understand please clearly am doing it first time

Comment: Does your client know that you are posting this here? Looks like a government URL. Aren't you under NDA from them?

Comment: First try running project in locally, I am sure you will get error there as well as it contain syntax error. later on You can connect from FTP and just check classes folder, to make sure class files are present and not lost in Data transfer.

Comment: can u please tell me ur email id so that i can show ur deployed Project structure which is running in our local server please help me dear

Comment: no yAAR tHILO AM jUST MAINTAINS

Comment: as per link given, I think you have error in your JSP file for package declaration. Your deployment comes later, first try solving all errors.

Comment: but same Folder i have run my local tomcat server its running Fine please with same package declaration

Comment: Jayesh will please deploy My Project u take some charge for that ?

Answer (score 0):

There are several things wrong, not the least of which is "only deploying JSP's through FTP", which is hacky, and as is evident from this problem, highly error prone. Since you're already using Tomcat, why not use the Tomcat Manager? That's what it's there for.

Judging from the output of the JSP, I'm guessing you have som old code lying around on the server, and that whatever JAR's contain mypackage.Utility, mypackage.GetFileContent and mypackage.LuceneFields are not the same as what you are using in your developer environment.

Comment: i AM NEW IN jSP pROJECT DEPLYING SO PLEASE SUGGEST I HAVE RUN MY PROJECT IN LOCAL tOMCAT SERVER PLEASE TELL ME STEP bY STEP SO THAT I CAN DEPLOY PLEASE

Comment: There is no such thing as a JSP project, so attempting to deploy one is meaningless. There are web applications, a subset of which are JSP (JavaServer Pages), another equally important aspect is the Java Classes that make up the rest of the application. If you only deploy the JSP pages without also deploying the rest of the application (or they fall out of sync), you will get errors like the ones you describe.

Comment: so please tell me Eject Solution what Should I Do so that i can deploy it?

Comment: You can't. You will need better infrastructure than FTP access to a webapp's WEB-INF folder in order to successfully deploy a complete webapp to the container.